# How to get maps to geopandas after datasets are removed?

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, geopandas

I have found very easy and useful to load world map from geopandas datasets, as probably many others, for example:

`import geopandas as gpd`

`world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))`

However, this gives a FutureWarning that dataset module is deprecated and will be removed in the future. There are maps available for download, for example from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/ but the files are zipped and it does not seem like a convinient workflow to either get and process files from there or neither include processed files with the source.

Is there an alternative? What is the best way to do this, especially if I want my code to work with future versions of Geopandas?

Comment: You could just download your data now, and upload a GeoJSON to somewhere, maybe as a GitHub Gist? Then, you can download that one now and work with it.

Comment: The removal is discussed in [this geopandas issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2751). The functionality has been moved to the new [geodatasets](https://geodatasets.readthedocs.io/en/latest) library.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to download/store the shapefile somewhere.

That being said, if (*for some reason*), you need to read it from the source, you can do it this [*way*](https://geopandas.org/en/v0.13.2/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-spatial-data) :

```
import fsspec

url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/" \
      "download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip"
    
with fsspec.open(f"simplecache::{url}") as file:
    gdf = gpd.read_file(file)
```

Output :

```
          featurecla  scalerank  ...     FCLASS_UA                            geometry
0    Admin-0 country          1  ...          None  MULTIPOLYGON (((180.00000 -16.0...
1    Admin-0 country          1  ...          None  POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34...
2    Admin-0 country          1  ...          None  POLYGON ((-8.66559 27.65643, -8...
..               ...        ...  ...           ...                                 ...
174  Admin-0 country          1  ...  Unrecognized  POLYGON ((20.59025 41.85541, 20...
175  Admin-0 country          1  ...          None  POLYGON ((-61.68000 10.76000, -...
176  Admin-0 country          1  ...          None  POLYGON ((30.83385 3.50917, 29....

[177 rows x 169 columns]
```

[image]

Comment: I think including the shapefile is a robust alternative and avoids problems with URLs changing etc. But this second option does not seem overly complicated either.. Just makes me sigh slightly that having data the data set included was so easy..

Answer (score 1):

For my jupyter notebooks, I have a `tools.py` where I store repeatedly used methods. One of them is `get_shapes()`, for getting frequently needed base-shapes (`world`-countries, `us`-states, `de`-states).

- Working folder relative paths:

  - `tools/tools.py`
  - `tools/__init__.py` (create an empty file)
- an absolute path would work, too - just replace `str(Path.cwd() / "tools")` below

Use as:

```py
from pathlib import Path
module_path = str(Path.cwd() / "tools")
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
from tools import tools

CRS_PROJ = "esri:54009" # Mollweide (e.g.)

world = tools.get_shapes(
    "world", shape_dir=Path.cwd() / "shapes")
world.to_crs(CRS_PROJ, inplace=True)
world.plot()
```

[image]

Can be (definitely) improved, but it is a start. Extend, if needed:

```py
import io
import csv
import requests
import geopandas as gp
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
from IPython.display import clear_output
from typing import List, Optional, Dict, Tuple
from IPython.core.display import display

def return_total(headers: Dict[str, str]):
    """Return total length from requests header"""
    if not headers:
        return 
    total_length = headers.get('content-length')
    if not total_length:
        return
    try:
        total_length = int(total_length)
    except:
        total_length = None
    return total_length

def stream_progress(total_length: int, loaded: int):
    """Stream progress report"""
    clear_output(wait=True)            
    perc_str = ""
    if total_length:
        total = total_length/1000000
        perc = loaded/(total/100)
        perc_str = f"of {total:.2f} ({perc:.0f}%)"
    print(
        f"Loaded {loaded:.2f} MB "
        f"{perc_str}..")

def stream_progress_basic(total: int, loaded: int):
    """Stream progress report"""
    clear_output(wait=True)            
    perc_str = ""
    if total:
        perc = loaded/(total/100)
        perc_str = f"of {total:.0f} ({perc:.0f}%)"
    print(
        f"Processed {loaded:.0f} "
        f"{perc_str}..")

def get_stream_file(url: str, path: Path):
    """Download file from url and save to path"""
    chunk_size = 8192
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        total_length = return_total(r.headers)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for ix, chunk in enumerate(r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size)): 
                f.write(chunk)
                loaded = (ix*chunk_size)/1000000
                if (ix % 100 == 0):
                    stream_progress(
                        total_length, loaded)
            stream_progress(
                total_length, loaded)
                        
def get_stream_bytes(url: str):
    """Stream file from url to bytes object (in-memory)"""
    chunk_size = 8192
    content = bytes()
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        total_length = return_total(r.headers)
        for ix, chunk in enumerate(r.iter_content(
                chunk_size=chunk_size)): 
            content += bytes(chunk)
            loaded = (ix*chunk_size)/1000000
            if (ix % 100 == 0):
                stream_progress(
                    total_length, loaded)
    stream_progress(
        total_length, loaded)
    return content
    
def get_folder_size(folder: Path):
    """Return size of all files in folder in MegaBytes"""
    if not folder.exists():
        raise Warning(
            f"Folder {folder} does not exist")
        return
    size_mb = 0
    for file in folder.glob('*'):
        size_mb += file.stat().st_size / (1024*1024)
    return size_mb
    
def get_zip_extract(
    uri: str, filename: str, output_path: Path, 
    create_path: bool = True, skip_exists: bool = True,
    report: bool = True, filter_files: List[str] = None,
    write_intermediate: bool = None):
    """Get Zip file and extract to output_path.
    Create Path if not exists."""
    if write_intermediate is None:
        write_intermediate = False
    if create_path:
        output_path.mkdir(
            exist_ok=True)
    if skip_exists and Path(
        output_path / filename.replace(".zip", ".csv")).exists():
        if report:
            print("File already exists.. skipping download..")
        return
    if write_intermediate:
        out_file = output_path / filename
        get_stream_file(f'{uri}{filename}', out_file)
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(out_file)
    else:
        content = get_stream_bytes(
            f'{uri}{filename}')
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(content))
    print("Extracting zip..")
    if filter_files:
        file_names = z.namelist()
        for filename in file_names:
            if filename in filter_files:
                z.extract(filename, output_path)
    else:
        z.extractall(output_path)
    if write_intermediate:
        if out_file.is_file():
            out_file.unlink()
    if report:
        raw_size_mb = get_folder_size(output_path)
        print(
            f"Retrieved {filename}, "
            f"extracted size: {raw_size_mb:.2f} MB")

def drop_cols_except(df: pd.DataFrame, columns_keep: List[str]):
    """Drop all columns from DataFrame except those specified in cols_except"""
    df.drop(
        df.columns.difference(columns_keep), axis=1, inplace=True)

def get_shapes(
        reference: str, shape_dir: Path,
        clean_cols: Optional[bool] = None, normalize_cols: Optional[bool] = None,
        set_index: Optional[bool] = None) -> gp.GeoDataFrame:
    """Custom method to get frequently used shapes (DE Bundesländer, US States)
    and return a geopandas.GeoDataFrame (WGS1984). Will only download shapes if 
    not already downloaded.

    reference: str - , "world", "us" and "de" are currently supported
    clean_cols: will remove all columns except geometry and state-reference. Defaults to True.
    normalize_cols: will rename columns to sane defaults. Defaults to True.
    set_index: will set state-reference as index column. Defaults to True.
    """
    if clean_cols is None:
        clean_cols = True
    if normalize_cols is None:
        normalize_cols = True
    if set_index is None:
        set_index = True
    target_name = "state"
    if reference == "us":
        source_zip = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/"
        filename = "cb_2018_us_state_5m.zip"
        shapes_name = "cb_2018_us_state_5m.shp"
        col_name = "NAME"
    elif reference == "de":
        source_zip = "https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/vg/vg2500/aktuell/"
        filename = "vg2500_12-31.utm32s.shape.zip"
        shapes_name = "vg2500_12-31.utm32s.shape/vg2500/VG2500_LAN.shp"
        col_name = "GEN"
    elif reference == "world":
        source_zip = "https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/cultural/"
        filename = "ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip"
        shapes_name = "ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp"
        col_name = "SOVEREIGNT"
        target_name = "country"
    # create  temporary storage folder, if not exists already
    shape_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    # test if file already downloaded
    if not (shape_dir / shapes_name).exists():
        get_zip_extract(
            uri=source_zip, filename=filename, output_path=shape_dir)
    else:
        print("Already exists")
    shapes = gp.read_file(shape_dir / shapes_name)
    if clean_cols:
        drop_cols_except(df=shapes, columns_keep=["geometry", col_name])
    if normalize_cols:
        shapes.rename(columns={col_name: target_name}, inplace=True)
        col_name = target_name
    if set_index:
        shapes.set_index(col_name, inplace=True)
    return shapes.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

Comment: `return_total` seems to be undefined; is it in another file or not included in tools.py or?

Comment: Ah, yes, added it - my `tools.py` contains many other methods not related to this answer, so I just copied what is needed, and missed `return_total()`.